# python's ".format" function

Tags: python, string, dictionary, formatting

Recently, I found `''.format` function very useful because it can improve readability a lot comparing to the `%` formatting.
Trying to achieve simple string formatting:

```
data = {'year':2012, 'month':'april', 'location': 'q2dm1'}

year = 2012
month = 'april'
location = 'q2dm1'
a = "year: {year}, month: {month}, location: {location}"
print a.format(data)
print a.format(year=year, month=month, location=location)
print a.format(year, month, location)
```

Whilst two first prints do format as I expect (yes, `something=something` looks ugly, but that's an example only), the last one would raise `KeyError: 'year'`.
Is there any trick in python to create dictionary so it will automatically fill keys and values, for example `somefunc(year, month, location)` will output `{'year':year, 'month': month, 'location': location}`?

I'm pretty new to python and couldn't find any info on this topic, however a trick like this would improve and shrink my current code drastically.

Thanks in advance and pardon my English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `print` should be

```
print a.format(**data)
```

Also, if you are finding some shortcuts, you could write one like, no big difference.

```
def trans(year, month, location):
    return dict(year=year, month=month, location=location)
```

Comment: Seems there's no way to shrink this repeating code:) Function is good and it was what i did, actually, but later i found it hard to sustain because with lots of arguments i needed to change code in several places, which turned out to be even worse than actually creating dict by hands.

Comment: @duke_nukem yes it depends on your actual usage. The code is fine and the format api is clear enough. If you what to achieve something like `format(*args, **kwargs)`, it could be done also, but I don't think it could make things easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {'year':2012, 'month':'april', 'location': 'q2dm1'}
a = "year: {year}, month: {month}, location: {location}"

print a.format(**data)
```

..is what you are looking for. It's functionally identical to doing `.format(year=data['year'], ...)`, or the other examples you gave.

The double-asterix thing is a hard thing to search for, so it's usually referred to as "kwargs". Here's a [good SO question on this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dict()` callable:

```
dict(year=yeah, month=month, location=location)
```

When passing keyword arguments it creates a dict containing the elements you specified as kwargs.

If you do not want to specify the argument names, use the positional style of `.format()`:

```
>>> a = 'year {0} month {1} location {2}'
>>> print a.format(2012, 'april', 'abcd')
year 2012 month april location abcd
```

However, if you try to do something similar to what [`compact()` in PHP](http://php.net/compact) does (create a dict mapping variable names to its values without specifying name and variable separately), please don't. It just results in ugly unreadable code and would require nasty hacks anyway.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of dict() but i'm trying to avoid unnecessary code and shrink it down a bit. .format can accept your option without dict() by the way. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, it's close to what i need, however with 10-12 arguments  it becomes pretty hard to navigate through indices.

Comment: Well in this case you are supposed to use the dict syntax. However, depending on what you want to do, consider using a real template engine such as [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the template direction.

Comment: Also, just adding, `dict` is not a function. `dict` is a type.

Comment: Well when used with `()` it's like a function. But I've replaced "function" with "callable" now...

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `locals()`:

```
a.format(**locals())
```

Of course, this has issues: you will have to pass everything in locals, and it can be difficult to understand the effect of renaming or removing a variable.

A better way would be:

```
a.format(**{k:v for k,v in locals() if k in ('year', 'month')})
# or; note that if you move the lambda expression elsewhere, you will get a different result
a.format(**(lambda ld = locals(): {k:ld[k] for k in ('year', 'month')})())
```

But this is not any more concise, unless you wrap it up with a function (which must of course take a dict parameter).

Answer (score 0):

As of [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html), you can also use the new  [**Formatted string literals (f-strings)**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals), which you can use with **variables**:

```
year = 2012
month = 'april'
location = 'q2dm1'
a = f"year: {year}, month: {month}, location: {location}"
print(a)
```

or a **dictionary**:

```
data = {'year': 2012, 'month': 'april', 'location': 'q2dm1'}
a = f"year: {data['year']}, month: {data['month']}, location: {data['location']}"
print(a)
```

Note the `f` prefix before the string literal.

> [**PEP 498: Formatted string literals**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):
>
> Formatted string literals are prefixed with 'f' and are similar to the
>   format strings accepted by str.format(). They contain replacement
>   fields surrounded by curly braces. The replacement fields are
>   expressions, which are evaluated at run time, and then formatted using
>   the format() protocol:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> name = "Fred"
> >>> f"He said his name is {name}."
> 'He said his name is Fred.'
> >>> width = 10
> >>> precision = 4
> >>> value = decimal.Decimal("12.34567")
> >>> f"result: {value:{width}.{precision}}"  # nested fields
> 'result:      12.35'
> ```
>
> ...