# How to pass variable into MySQLdb query with Python?

Tags: python, mysql, loops

I'm trying to loop over an MySQL query, however I can't get the variable to work. What am I doing wrong? The loop starts at line 10.

```
cur = db.cursor()
query = '''
Select user_id, solution_id 
From user_concepts
Where user_id IN 
  (Select user_id FROM fields);
'''    
cur.execute(query)
numrows = cur.rowcount
for i in xrange(0,numrows):
    row = cur.fetchone()
# find all item_oid where task_id = solution_id for first gallery and      sort by influence.
    cur.execute('''
        SELECT task_id, item_oid, influence
        FROM solution_oids 
        WHERE task_id = row[%d]
        ORDER BY influence DESC;
        ''', (i))
    cur.fetchall()
```

error message:

> File "james_test.py", line 114, in ''', (i))
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
>   query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this.  You may not need to declare 2 cursors, but it won't hurt anything.  Sometimes a second cursor is necessary because there could be a conflict.  Notice how I demonstrate 2 different methods for looping the cursor data. One with the fetchall and one by looping the cursor.  A third method could use fetch, but is not shown.  Using a dictionary cursor is really nice, but sometimes you may want to use a standard non-dict cursor where values are retrieved only by their number in the row array.  Also note the need to use a trailing comma in the parameter list when you have only 1 parameter.  Because it expects a tuple.  If you have more than 1 parameter, you won't need a trailing comma because more than 1 parm will be a tuple.

```
cursor1 = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)  # a dictcursor enables a named hash
cursor2 = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)  # a dictcursor enables a named hash

cursor1.execute("""
    Select user_id, solution_id 
      From user_concepts
     Where user_id IN (Select user_id FROM fields);
"""    

for row in cursor1.fetchall():
    user_id = row["user_id"]
    solution_id = row["solution_id"]

    cursor2.execute("""
        SELECT task_id, item_oid, influence
        FROM solution_oids 
        WHERE task_id = %s
        ORDER BY influence DESC;
    """, (solution_id,))

    for data in cursor2:
        task_id = data["task_id"]
        item_oid = data["item_oid"]
        influence = data["influence"]
```

Comment: That helped me with much more than my question. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

`cur.execute` expect a `tuple` o `dict` for params but you gave `(i)` which is an `int` not a `tuple`. To make it a `tuple` add a comma `(i,)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
a = '''this is the {try_}. try'''
i= 1    
b = a.format(try_=i)
print b
```

You could even do:

```
data = {'try_':i}
b = a.format(**data)
```

sources:

[python's ".format" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160390/pythons-format-function)

[Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)